# Remove CYGWIN from Windows XP

Tags: windows, cygwin

Can I remove CYGWIN completely from Win - files, services and everithing ?
I've a service for sshd, which does not work. When I try to start it - error 1067. And I can`t remove it, too. When I tried it says that there is no such service !?!?
Maybe there is some problems with the "pre-installing", because once deleted the whole cygwin folder

Comment: belongs to superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use cygrunsrv to remove services. After that I usually just delete the entire cygwin directory, though that doesn't clean up the registery or the start menu entries.

(If you've already deleted the cygwin folder, then cygrunsrv obviously won't work.)